# c++ directx 9 lockvertexbuffer throws exception

Tags: c++, directx-9

when using ID3DXBaseMesh::LockVertexBuffer I get an unhandled exception
here is the code:

```
HRESULT ScaleMesh(ID3DXMesh *pMesh, float scale, D3DXVECTOR3 *offset=NULL)
{
BYTE *ptr=NULL;
HRESULT hr;
D3DXVECTOR3 vOff;

// return failure if no mesh pointer set
if (!pMesh)
    return D3DERR_INVALIDCALL;

// select default or specified offset vector
if (offset)
    vOff=*offset;
else
    vOff=D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

// get the face count
DWORD numVerts=pMesh->GetNumVertices();

// get the FVF flags
DWORD fvf=pMesh->GetFVF();

// calculate vertex size
DWORD vertSize=D3DXGetFVFVertexSize(fvf);

// lock the vertex buffer
if (FAILED(hr=pMesh->LockVertexBuffer(0,&ptr)))

    // return on failure
    return hr;

// loop through the vertices
for (DWORD i=0;i<numVerts;i++) {

    // get pointer to location
    D3DXVECTOR3 *vPtr=(D3DXVECTOR3 *) ptr;

    // scale the vertex
    *vPtr+=vOff;
    vPtr->x*=scale;
    vPtr->y*=scale;
    vPtr->z*=scale;

    // increment pointer to next vertex
    ptr+=vertSize;
}

// unlock the vertex buffer
if (FAILED(hr=pMesh->UnlockVertexBuffer()))

    // return on failure
    return hr;

// return success to caller
return S_OK;
}
```

the exception is at pMesh->LockVertextBuffer();

Comment: what's the exception said?

Comment: why are you using `BYTE` instead of a vertex structure with position, normal.. etc fields for the vertex buffer? I think this the cause of your unhandled exception.